# Can't see a file in Windows written by an Android app on SD card unless I "Force Close" the app

Tags: android, windows-explorer, android-sdcard, filewriter

I wrote a file through my Android program like this:

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Files/hello.txt";
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
writer.write(str + "\n");     \\ Yeah, 'str' has a value there
writer.close();
```

The program does its job and it finishes. Now I hit the back button on Android to close the application. If I then go to an Android file browser (like Astro) I can see the file, but if I mount the SD card on Windows, I can't see the file!

Now, if I go to *Settings* → *Applications* → *Manage Applications* → *"Force Stop" <application>*, I'm able to see the file even in Windows.

What should I do so that I can see a file in Windows if the file is written by my Android app on the SD card and I don't want to go to settings and hit force close every time.

Actually the file is being written properly (I think), but since the default behaviour of Android 'back' button doesn't kill the app, and it looks like unless the app is killed I can't open the file outside Android (in Android, I'm still able to see it and even open it).

So, what would be the best solution for this case? Should I automatically kill the app when it is closing? People say that System.exit() is strictly not recommended.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Have you been able to solve it since you have asked your question?

Answer (score 27):

It´s necessary that you use the following code so that your archive will be shown in the file system of Windows or in the gallery of the phone.

You have two possibilities:

1. It´s faster because Android updates only the file passed:

   `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{"your path here</"}, null, null);`
2. It´s more expensive because Android will search all the files in the path passed. You can pass only the path of the folder to reduce the search of the files:

   ```
   context.sendBroadcast(
       new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                  Uri.parse("file://" + "path of the folder")));
   ```

Comment: This really should be up voted more - good solution to probably a common problem.

Comment: Thanks. I hope that this solution help a lot of developers.

Comment: Unfortunately the sendBroadcast way no longer works as of Kitkat Android 4.4. :(

Comment: i have the same problem, i saved a text files into my sd card with my app, and Window explorer can't see them where as i change the name of the files in the manage file of the tablet , the files appear in windows explorer ... i don't know why it's do this

Comment: @ThomasTrabelsi I will check this issue and I going to reply you a probable fix.

Comment: @thiagolsilva Where is your "probable fix"?

Answer (score 0):

Because a BufferedWriter object is a *buffer*, you need to flush() the buffer to force the content to be written to the output stream.

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Files/hello.txt";
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));   
writer.write(str+"\n");
writer.flush(); // force the buffer to actually dump its data to the stream
writer.close();
```

When you .write() using a buffer, always remember that the data will be held in the buffer until either the buffer is filled (and then automagically flush()ed) or you force the buffer to flush its data using the .flush() method of the buffer.

Additionally, the reason the file wasn't being written to correctly until you force-closed the application is because when you kill an application, one of the steps taken is to flush() all buffers associated with the application. That's why this was only happening when you force-killed it.

**Note:** Bear in mind that this is the default behavior of most kinds of buffered streams in many different languages.

Comment: `.close()` is automatically calling `.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 did have issues seeing files when connected through the USB connection. The workaround for me was using a GNU/Linux distribution.

Using a terminal app, there is a difference where `root:root` files are viewable on Explorer, but no other owners.

Comment: Could you please explain more the contest of your solution?