# Write a file world readable on smartphone's memory

Tags: android, storage, android-file

I am trying to access a file that i fill thanks to my app. I am storing it on my phone's memory, but not on my app's internal memory.

My problem is that the file doesn't exist when I open it on my PC (with phone connected via USB). But it is available and not empty when I open it directly from my smartphone.

I need this file to be available on my computer.

#### On my manifest:

```
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

#### I have tried this way:

```
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("my_app/data/file.txt");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
out.append("text");
out.flush();
out.close();
```

#### And also this way:

```
 File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("my_app/data/file.txt");
 FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
 printStream.println(text);
 printStream.close();
```

#### Another way..

```
File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("my_app/data/file.txt");
FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(file);
BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(outFile);
buf.write("hey");
buf.close();
outFile.close();
```

Some of those solutions work, but only on my phone so it isn't world readable, others just don't work...

What is the difference between `OutPutStreamWriter`, `FileWriter`, `BufferedWriter`, `FileOutputStream`, `PrintWriter`, ...? Which one do I have to choose?

How do I manage to create my public file in order to access it directly from my computer?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe because it is still open somewhere else?

Comment: No, this isn't the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String toWrite = "save me to disk";
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY); 
if (!dir.exists()) {
    dir.mkdirs();
}
File file = new File(dir, INSTALLATION_FILE);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file );
out.write(toWrite.getBytes());
out.close();
```

Comment: no it still doesn't work. My file is created and the text is written on my phone, but when i try to see this same file with my PC, the folder is empty...

Comment: This method has been tested by me and it works. So maybe the problem lies with the pc connection. Do you see the file using the ADB shell?

Comment: Yes I can see the file in Android Debug Monitor, but I can't see it in my file explorer.

Comment: short search yielded these results, try what they suggest:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391432/unable-to-see-file-in-windows-explorer-while-it-is-visible-in-android-file-brows 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429087/cant-see-a-file-in-windows-written-by-an-android-app-on-sd-card-unless-i-force

Comment: It works for me with this:

`context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+"my_path"))));`

Thank you for your time!